# o110.pyWriteDynamicFrame. null

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I have created a visual job in AWS Glue where I extract data from Snowflake and then my target is a postgresql database in AWS.

I have been able to connect to both Snowflak and Postgre, I can preview data from both.

I have also been able to get data from snoflake, write to s3 as csv and then take that csv and upload it to postgre.

However when I try to get data from snowflake and push it to postgre I get the below error:

o110.pyWriteDynamicFrame. null

Answer (score 0):

So it means that you can get the data from snowflake in a Datafarme and while writing the data from this datafarme to postgres, you are failing.
You need to check was glue logs to get more understanding why is this failing while writing the data into postgres.
Please check if you have the right version of jars (needed by postgres) compatible with scala(on was glue side).

Comment: Hi Anshul, the connection to postgres is with the built n JDBC connector from GLUE and it is to a RDS postgres db. The connector for snowflake is working because I can preview the data and get the schema. Not sure where else to look